# Python wont allow me to import .py files from same directory

Tags: python

So I'm just starting to learn Python, and I am learning classes and imports, but for some reason even when I follow the same code as my book say to do, I get a traceback error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Programming/Desktop/Programs/EX40/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import objects.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'objects.py'; 'objects' is not a package
```

Here is both my Python files in which I'm trying to link:

main.py

```
import objects.py

print(MyStuff.tangerine)
```

objects.py

```
class MyStuff(object):
    def __init__(self, arm):
        self.tangerine = 'And now a thousand years between'
        self.arm = arm

    def apple(self):
        print('I AM CLASSY APPLES!')
```

Comment: Try `import objects` instead of `import objects.py`

Comment: `import objects.py` looks for a file `objects/py.py`.

Comment: Seems like you're a beginner and should probably go over [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) for these kind of basic things

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import objects
```

Because it takes `py` as a module in the `objects` file which does not exist

Comment: When I try this I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Programming/Desktop/Programs/EX40/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(MyStuff.tangerine)
NameError: name 'MyStuff' is not defined

Comment: @JustinBarefoot you need `objects.MyStuff.tangerine` or alternatively import as `from objects import MyStuff`

Answer (score 0):

`import objects.py` is not a valid import

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Try

```
from objects import MyStuff
```

Instantiating the class:

```
mystuff = MyStuff("arm value")
print(mystuff.tangerine)
```

Comment: When I try that I get this:                                                                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Programming/Desktop/Programs/EX40/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(MyStuff.tangerine)
AttributeError: type object 'MyStuff' has no attribute 'tangerine'

Comment: you have to instantiate the object first or the stuff in __init__ never gets called, I have updated my answer

Comment: `MyStuff` takes one positional argument

Comment: Ah shoot yeah didn't notice that, fixed my example